# Extract string from position X to position Y from TXT files

Tags: vbscript

Select "Show pictures" to display embedded pictures. Show pictures

I have many txt files and I need to extract data from them for inserting in an SQL DB

the files are something like bellow:

"DESCRIPTION USER TIME       FIELD"

"-------------       ------   ----------  -----------"

"XXXX                 YY01 12:01:01 SAMPLE"

It's like some sort of columns, and the rule is only the position and length of each column, determined by those lines (-----) beneath each column header description

I need to extract string from position X to Y from each line and maybe write that in another file or somewhere( this is not difficult)

I need a code that will parse each line from that txt and return string from position x to position Y for every line in txt

How can I do that in vbscript or C++/#...or powershell maybe, in the end I will do some exe or batch that will extract this automatically

Any help would be appreciated as I'm not very familiar with coding

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple vbscript routine which uses a delimiter to split

```
const ForWriting = 2, ForReading = 1
set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oInFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(sFilenameIn, ForReading)
do While oInFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    sLine = oInFile.readline 'skip the first tow lines or use a condition to check for content
    sLine = oInFile.readline
    sLine = oInFile.readline
    a = split(sLine," ") 'here the delimiter is a space, parse line in array
    field1 = a(1) 'YY01 for the first data line
    field2 = a(2) '12:01:01 for the first data line
    'do something with the data
loop
```

If you can't use a delimiter use something like

```
field1 = mid(sLine, 6, 4) 'YY01 for the first data line
```